# Using & in align

Tags: align

Consider the following code and its outcome:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
 A >& B > C &> D \\
 A >& E &>D
\end{align}

\begin{eqnarray}
 A >& B > C &> D \\
 A >& E &> D
\end{eqnarray}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I want the outcome to be the second one rather than the first one.
However, I want to achieve this in the align environment.

1. Can I do this?
2. What does the & exactly do anyway?

EDIT: Thanks for the help so far. I like (and upvoted) all options proposed, but what if I want BOTH lines to be numbered? So instead of `align*`, `align`.

Comment: Does it need to be align, or can it be one of the other AMS environments?

Comment: I am curious about align, but another environment would be fine for now - as long as it is in amsmath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A variant with `alignat`  and `eqmakebox`, mimicking the construction of the `\vdotswithin` command from `mathtools`:
    \documentclass{article}

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{3}
 A & > B & & \eqmakebox[A]{$ {}>{} $} C &&> D \\
 A & > & & \eqmakebox[A]{$ E $}& & >D
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*An explanation on the ampersands usage*

The only difference between `align` and `alignat` is that the spacing between the columns of aligned equations is chosen by the user in the case of the `alignat` environment.

For *n* columns, you have to use *2n – 1* `&`: from the 2nd one, each `&` marks the beginning of a new column, the following `&` marks the alignment point in its column.

Here, I set `3` columns, whence `5&`, with no spacing between the columns.

Answer (score 6):

This is better realized with an array:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\[
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{array}{c *{3}{ >{{}}c<{{}} c } }
A &> & B &> & C &> & D \\
A &> & \multicolumn{3}{c}{E} &> & D
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Seven points of alignment, the even numbered column for the relation symbol, so surrounded by empty subformula in order to produce the correct space. Intercolumn padding is set (locally) to zero.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be a good solution +1
But what if, additionally, I want to number both (chains of inequalities). If I replace the \[ with, say, \begin{align}, \end{align} I only get a single number tag.

Comment: @Bayesian That's more complicated and possibly requires to see the real thing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `alignat` instead of `align` and then some low level commands to get the centering or you can use the `eqnarray` package.

## alignat

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ccol}[1]{\omit\column@plus\hfill$\m@th\displaystyle #1$\hfill\span}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
 A >{}& B > C &&> D \\
 A >{}&\ccol{E}&>D
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

## equationarray

[image: Second sample]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{eqnarray}

\begin{document}

\arraycolsep 0pt
\begin{equationarray}{rcl}
 A >{}& B > C &{}> D \\
 A >{}&E&{}>D
\end{equationarray}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Also a nice option! +1
But as with the answet above: If I wanted to number both lines, alignat would just number the first one, right?

Comment: No, `alignat` numbers each line.  I have updated the code and provided a convenient macro for the centered column.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you don't need the individual equations numbered, here it is with a TABstack.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\TABstackMath
\begin{document}
\[
\setstacktabulargap{0pt}
\TABbinary
\tabularCenterstack{rcl}{
 A >& B > C &> D \\
 A >& E &> D
}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]